# UWP XAML Change Background of ListView When Child Selected

Tags: xaml, listview, uwp

I have two ListViews on the same screen.  The background of the ListView and all its ListViewItems needs to change when one of the items in the ListView has focus (while keeping the background of the OTHER ListView and its items unchanged).

[image]

I tried adding a VisualStateManager to the Border in the ListView's ControlTemplate but it doesn't seem to be working.

In the XAML below, you can see that the border and background of the ListViews are supposed to be getting set to "HotPink" when the control is selected.

I'm guessing this has something to do with how "focus" and "selected" are not the same thing?  I can't find a list of the ListView visual states anywhere.  They're not even in the template file, which I thought listed all of them.

If possible, I'd like to achieve this purely through XAML, but if it's not possible, that's okay.

```
<Page
    x:Class="MyApp.Views.BlankPage1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:CardiologyApp.Views"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="CadetBlue">
    <Page.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ListViewStyle1" TargetType="ListView">
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Once"/>
            <Setter Property="IsSwipeEnabled" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Disabled"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Enabled"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.ZoomMode" Value="Disabled"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}"/>
            <Setter Property="ItemContainerTransitions">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TransitionCollection>
                        <AddDeleteThemeTransition/>
                        <ContentThemeTransition/>
                        <ReorderThemeTransition/>
                        <EntranceThemeTransition IsStaggeringEnabled="False"/>
                    </TransitionCollection>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListView">
                        <Border x:Name="ListViewBorder"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderThickness="2"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                CornerRadius="3">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="ListViewBorder.RevealBorderBrush" Value="HotPink"/>
                                            <Setter Target="ListViewBorder.Background" Value="HotPink"/>
                                            <Setter Target="ListViewBorder.RevealBackground" Value="HotPink"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="ListViewBorder.RevealBorderBrush" Value="HotPink"/>
                                            <Setter Target="ListViewBorder.Background" Value="HotPink"/>
                                            <Setter Target="ListViewBorder.RevealBackground" Value="HotPink"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <ScrollViewer
                                x:Name="ScrollViewer"
                                AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding
                                ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}"
                                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding
                                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
                                IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}"
                                IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding
                                ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled}"
                                IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding
                                ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}"
                                IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding
                                ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}"
                                IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled}"
                                TabNavigation="{TemplateBinding TabNavigation}"
                                VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
                                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding
                                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                ZoomMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ZoomMode}">
                                <ItemsPresenter
                                    Footer="{TemplateBinding Footer}"
                                    FooterTransitions="{TemplateBinding FooterTransitions}"
                                    FooterTemplate="{TemplateBinding FooterTemplate}"
                                    Header="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                    HeaderTransitions="{TemplateBinding HeaderTransitions}"
                                    HeaderTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ListViewItemTemplate1" TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <ListViewItemPresenter
                x:Name="Root"
                CheckBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBrush}"
                ContentMargin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                CheckBoxBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBoxBrush}"
                ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                CheckMode="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckMode}"
                DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}"
                DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"
                DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackground}"
                DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForeground}"
                FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusBorderBrush}"
                FocusVisualMargin="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualMargin}"
                FocusSecondaryBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusSecondaryBorderBrush}"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True"
                PressedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundPressed}"
                PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackground}"
                PointerOverForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemForegroundPointerOver}"
                PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundPointerOver}"
                RevealBorderThickness="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderThemeThickness}"
                ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
                RevealBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderBrush}"
                RevealBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBackground}"
                SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemForegroundSelected}"
                SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled}"
                SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundSelected}"
                SelectedPressedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundSelectedPressed}"
                SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver}"
                VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Selected"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver"/>
                                <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverSelected">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver"/>
                                <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverPressed">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed"/>
                                <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed"/>
                                <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="PressedSelected">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed"/>
                                <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DisabledStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Enabled"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </ListViewItemPresenter>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Canvas>
        <ListView Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="100" Width="200" Height="500" Style="{StaticResource ListViewStyle1}">
            <ListViewItem Template="{StaticResource ListViewItemTemplate1}">Vessel 1</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem Template="{StaticResource ListViewItemTemplate1}">Vessel 2</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem Template="{StaticResource ListViewItemTemplate1}">Vessel 3</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem Template="{StaticResource ListViewItemTemplate1}">Vessel 4</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem Template="{StaticResource ListViewItemTemplate1}">Vessel 5</ListViewItem>
        </ListView>

        <ListView Canvas.Left="500" Canvas.Top="100" Width="200" Height="500" Style="{StaticResource ListViewStyle1}">
            <ListViewItem Template="{StaticResource ListViewItemTemplate1}">Location 1</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem Template="{StaticResource ListViewItemTemplate1}">Location 2</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem Template="{StaticResource ListViewItemTemplate1}">Location 3</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem Template="{StaticResource ListViewItemTemplate1}">Location 4</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem Template="{StaticResource ListViewItemTemplate1}">Location 5</ListViewItem>
        </ListView>
    </Canvas>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you select the listViewItem, it triggers the "selected" of the ListViewItem instead of ListView's. It's better to use Binding to achieve it. You can create a viewmodel includes the color binded to the the background of the ListView or ListViewItem. When trigger the click event, change the color. For example:

.xaml:

```
<ListView Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="100" Width="200" Height="500" x:Name="FirstListView" Background="{x:Bind viewmodel.MyBackgroundColor,Mode=OneWay}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick">
    ......
</ListView>

<ListView Canvas.Left="500" Canvas.Top="100" Width="200" Height="500" x:Name="SecondListView" Background="{x:Bind viewmodel.OtherBackgroundColor,Mode=OneWay}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick">
    ......
</ListView>
```

.cs

```
public class MyColorModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    private SolidColorBrush myBackgroundColor { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush MyBackgroundColor
    {
        get { return myBackgroundColor; }
        set
        {
            myBackgroundColor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private SolidColorBrush otherBackgroundColor { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush OtherBackgroundColor
    {
        get { return otherBackgroundColor; }
        set
        {
            otherBackgroundColor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

private void ListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    ListView listView = sender as ListView;
    if (listView.Name == "FirstListView")
    {
        viewmodel.MyBackgroundColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.HotPink);
    }
    else 
    {
        viewmodel.OtherBackgroundColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
    }
}
```